# Multiple clock generation [Verilog] [Using fork-join]

Tags: verilog, clock, fork-join

I generated the following code :

```
module clk_gen();
    reg clk, clk1 , clk2, clk3 , clk4 ;  

always 
    fork 
       #5 clk = ~clk ;
       #1 clk1 = ~clk1 ;
       #3 clk2 = ~clk2 ;
       #4 clk3 = ~clk3 ;
       #3 clk4 = ~clk4 ;
    join


 initial begin
    clk = 1'b0 ;  
    clk1 = 1'b0 ;  
    clk2 = 1'b0 ;  
    clk3 = 1'b0 ;  
    clk4 = 1'b0 ;  
    $monitor ("Time : %0t ,RealTime : %0t ,Clk Value : %0d,Clk1 Value : %0d,Clk2 Value : %0d,Clk3 Value : %0d,Clk4 Value : %0d,$time,$realtime,clk,clk1,clk2,clk3,clk4) ;

    #30 $finish ;
 end

endmodule : clk_gen
```

I am not able to generate the clocks using the fork-join statement.All clocks generated are of the same frequency i.e of #5 delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` will wait till all thread finish, so actually for the longest one (#5). This is why all clocks are synchronized at 5 cycles.

you do not need a fork there. just use multiple always statements.

```
always 
   #5 clk = ~clk ;
always
   #1 clk1 = ~clk1 ;
always    
   #3 clk2 = ~clk2 ;
   ...
```

you can potentially use fork/join like this:

```
initial begin
    fork
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;
        forever #4 clk1 = ~clk1;
        ...
    join 
 end
```

which would be the same as using mulitpile initial blocks

```
 initial forever #5 clk = ~clk;
```

Comment: I have been to write using mutiple always statement. But was wondering would there be a way to write it using fork-join only

Comment: There might be a way, i.e. you cans start `forever` loops with delays in a fork thread. But why such a complication?

Comment: Read that there is a way using fork join, in another thread. So tried it myself but didn't succeed. And that thread was now closed

Comment: @NitinSharma  I added an example for fork/join which might work to my answer

Comment: I have a follow up question. How does the always loop work in my case as no sensitivity list is provided. When I do " always @* " the simulation results are different. What is the difference between always and always @(*)

Comment: `always` with no sensitivity list is executed in  a similar way as a 'forever' loop. If there are no delays init, your simulation will just hang there forever. delays pause it and allow other parts of simulation to continue. `always @*` will wait for changes in the sensitivity list before execution.

Comment: Thanks Serge, this has cleared my concept of working of the always block

Answer (score 0):

This way of clock generation can't be done thorugh any of the `fork-join` methods (fork-join, fork-join_any, fork-join_none).

The reason is that

- With `fork-join`, it will wait for the longest thread to be completed, and hence the period will be equal to the longest thread delay.
- With `fork-join_any`, it will be completed as soon as the 1st shortest delay thread gets completed, but however after that it will spawn multiple threads and hence the period will be equal to the shortest thread delay.
- With `fork-join_none`, infinite threads will be generated.

Hence ideal solution is to make separate `always` blocks for each clocks.

```
always #5 clk = ~clk ;
always #1 clk1 = ~clk1 ;
always #3 clk2 = ~clk2 ;
always #4 clk3 = ~clk3 ;
always #3 clk4 = ~clk4 ;
```

Comment: neither `join_none` nor `join_any` are available in verilog. These are `system verilog` features.

Comment: Yes true. I was just explaining that they wont work.